# Regex for Lastname within letter range

Tags: php, regex

Im not that good in building regular expressions.
Thats why im asking you! :)

So, im working with letter ranges which stand for the beginning of the lastname, for example:

```
1: X-Y
2: Ki-Kj
3: Al-Bkz
```

The ranges all stand for a specific process, thats why I need to know which regex fits to the lastname.

The lastname "Albert" would fit into regex #3, "Kioto" would fit into #2.
I hope that makes sense to you.

The regex also needs to be complex enough to handle ranges like "Bauer-Schmidt".

I really, really need your help!

Comment: Really not a regex issue ... You should use simple string comparison against the lower and upper boundaries of each interval instead.

Comment: But how can i compare to the ranges that are between the defined paramters? For example "Ab-De". How can i compare my lastname which starts with "Co" ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more what you need exactly, do you need to filter all last names that starts with couple of letters and ends with couple of letters, please update your question

Comment: so where "Bauer-Schmidt" should fit ? is it #3

Comment: "Bauer-Schmidt" in this case is also a range, from "Bauer" to "Schmidt" and all lastnames between that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really not a problem that you should use regex for in the first place ... Use simple string comparison against the lower and upper boundaries of each interval instead.

```
function check_name_in_range($name) {
  $ranges = [
    1 => ['X', 'Y'],
    2 => ['Ki', 'Kj'],
    3 => ['Al', 'Bkz'],
  ];
  foreach($ranges as $rangeNum => $range) {
    if( substr($name, 0, strlen($range[0])) >= $range[0] &&
        substr($name, 0, strlen($range[1])) <= $range[1] ) {
      return $name. ' falls into range ' . $rangeNum;
    }
  }
  return $name. ' does not fall into any range';
}

var_dump(
  check_name_in_range('Albert'),
  check_name_in_range('Kjooto'),
  check_name_in_range('FitsEffAll')
);
```

You might wan to lowercase all involved strings before comparison, so that `A`/`a` doesn't become an issue, because those are *not* equal.

Comment: Does this also work if i have range that only contains the start "Alz"?
Or does this also give me the name "Button" which is >= Alz but wouldnt fit the rule.

Comment: You mean a range with only one boundary, so only one element in the corresponding array entry? No, that won't work, not unless you modify the code to check for that. But do you really need that? If you want to catch every thing that is greater, say `Foo`, in a range - then you could simply make `Z` the upper boundary.

Comment: If i take the lastname "Kjooto", which should fit into "Ki-Kj" your code doesnt work.

Comment: Right, for that to work, we must only compare as many characters of the name, as the boundary itself is long - check the updated code, that takes that int account, too.

Comment: So, this really seems to work! Thank you so much!
But i still have the problem left, that the range could only contain 1 letter, "A" for example, or only "Azk". How could i handle that?

Comment: In the way that I already told you - use a range from `Azk` to `Z`.

Comment: But "Azk" to "Z" would also contain names like "Bauer" or "Goldi".
In my case "Azk" stands only for names that start with "Azk".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you asking for but what i understand do like this

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}
```

this will give you like albert to al.
If you want only uppercase letters, then:

```
[A-Z]{2}
```

Please free to comment what you exactly want.
Thanks